How to calculate this n-order determinant?
The original problem: 
$\begin{vmatrix}1+x_1y_1&1+x_1^2y_2&\ldots&1+x_1^ny_n\\1+x_2y_1&1+x_2^2y_2&\ldots&1+x_2^ny_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\1+x_ny_1&1+x_n^2y_2&\ldots&1+x_n^ny_n\end{vmatrix}$
I try to bordered it to solve it like:
$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1&\ldots&1\\0&1+x_1y_1&1+x_1^2y_2&\ldots&1+x_1^ny_n\\0&1+x_2y_1&1+x_2^2y_2&\ldots&1+x_2^ny_n\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\0&1+x_ny_1&1+x_n^2y_2&\ldots&1+x_n^ny_n\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1&\ldots&1\\-1&x_1y_1&x_1^2y_2&\ldots&x_1^ny_n\\-1&x_2y_1&x_2^2y_2&\ldots&x_2^ny_n\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\-1&x_ny_1&x_n^2y_2&\ldots&x_n^ny_n\end{vmatrix}\\=-y_1y_2\cdots y_n\begin{vmatrix}-1&\frac{1}{y_1}&\frac{1}{y_2}&\ldots&\frac{1}{y_n}\\1&x_1&x_1^2&\ldots&x_1^n\\1&x_2&x_2^2&\ldots&x_2^n\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\1&x_n&x_n^2&\ldots&x_n^n\end{vmatrix}$
Then try to expand it by row-one and we need to approach (n-1) of Vandermonde Determinant with missing terms that I got no idea.

in  Mathematica consider the quotient of the $4\times 4$ determinant divided by the Vandermonde determinant in $x_i$ and diagonal matrix in $x_i*y_i$
 Det[Array[(1 + Subscript[x, #1]^#2 Subscript[y, #2] &), {4, 4}]]/
     Det@VandermondeMatrix[Array[Subscript[x, #] &, {4}]]/
 Det[DiagonalMatrix[ Array[Subscript[x, #] Subscript[y, #] &, {4}]]] // 
 FullSimplify // Expand

After factorization we get
$$1+\frac{1}{y_1}\left(\frac{1}{x_2}+\frac{1}{x_3}+\frac{1}{x_4}+\frac{1}{x_1}\right) -\frac{1}{y_2}\left( \frac{1}{x_1 x_3}+\frac{1}{x_2 x_3}+\frac{1}{x_1 x_4}+\frac{1}{x_2 x_4}+\frac{1}{x_3 x_4}+\frac{1}{x_1 x_2} \right) +\frac{1}{y_3}\left( \frac{1}{x_1 x_2 x_4}+\frac{1}{x_1 x_3 x_4}+\frac{1}{x_2 x_3 x_4}+\frac{1}{x_1 x_2 x_3} \right) -\frac{1}{y_4}\frac{1}{x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4}$$
This is a sum over inverses of $y_i$ with inverse products in subsets of $x_k$ of length i with sign change for i odd or even. The formula persist for n=5. No more checks done.

Seemingly the result is true. Fine, I will explore the solution based on this known result. Thank you!

This isn't a complete answer but I can motivate and partially validate the result inferred by Roland F. Let $A$ be the original matrix and let $u$ be a column $n$-vector of ones. Then $uu^\top$ is a matrix of ones, so
\begin{align}
A-uu^\top
&=\begin{pmatrix}x_1y_1&x_1^2y_2&\ldots&x_1^ny_n\\x_2y_1&x_2^2y_2&\ldots&x_2^ny_n\\\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\x_ny_1&x_n^2y_2&\ldots&x_n^ny_n\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\text{diag}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}1&x_1 &\ldots&x_1^{n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
1&x_n&\ldots&x_n^{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \text{diag}(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)\\
\end{align}
which we express compactly as $A=XVY+uu^\top$. Then $A$ is a rank-one update of $XVY$, so the matrix determinant lemma yields
$$\det{A}=\det(XVY+uu^\top)=\det(XVY)(1+u^\top(XVY)^{-1} u)$$
Since $\det(XVY)=\det(YXV)=\det(YX)\det(V)$, we recognize $\det(A)/\det(XVY)$ as the quotient considered by Roland F. It remains to compute $u^\top(XVY)^{-1} u=u^\top Y^{-1}V^{-1}X^{-1}u$ and thereby validate the formula deduced from Mathematica.

Finally, I proceed my progress by proving a lemma that in Vandermonde Determinant, if we delete the i-th row and add $(x_1^n,x_2^n,\cdots,x_n^n)$ to the end row, then the determinant is
$\sigma_{n-i+1}V_n(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$.
By this lemma, I continue my formula to be :
$=-y_1y_2\cdots y_nV(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)(-x_1x_2\cdots x_n-\frac{1}{y_1}\sigma_{n-1}+\frac{1}{y_2}\sigma_{n-2}-\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{1}{y_n})\\
=y_1y_2\cdots y_nV(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)(x_1x_2\cdots x_n+\frac{1}{y_1}\sigma_{n-1}-\frac{1}{y_2}\sigma_{n-2}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{y_n})$
Then the result is actually the same as the formula given by Roland F.
